# Call renderPartial from routes.php OctoberCMS

Tags: static, routes, octobercms, renderpartial

I'm trying to render partial from routes.php

```
Route::get('/redirect', function () {
    $response = Cms\Classes\ComponentBase::renderPartial('::basket-paypal', $_GET);
    return [
            $responseID => $response
        ];
});
```

Gives me non-static call.
Is it possible at all to call ComponentBase class for return partial? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Was searching in wrong direction

Solution is to make view

```
 Route::get('/redirect/{id}', function ($id) {
    $order = \Jiri\JKShop\Models\Order::find($id);
    $data = array(
        'id'            =>  $order->id,
        'CustomerName'  =>  $order->ds_first_name .' '. $order->ds_last_name,
        'TotalPrice'    =>  $order->total_price,
    );

    return Response::view('alexela.shopextend::response', $data);
});
```

folder in plugin directory : views\response.php
That's all.
Hope will help someone..